# I'm trying to access aurora DB through ssh tunneling in python, but I'm having a problem. Could not establish session to SSH gateway

Tags: python, database, ssh, pymysql

```py
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import pymysql

try:   
    with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('10.100.100.10', 22),
        ssh_username="ec2-user",
        ssh_pkey="key.pem",
        remote_bind_address=('prd-example-aurora.cluster-ro-example.ap-northeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com', 3306)
    ) as tunnel:
        print("== SSH Tunnel ==")

        db = pymysql.connect(
            host='127.0.0.1', user="example",
            password="example", port=tunnel.local_bind_port
        )
        # Run sample query in the database to validate connection
        try:
            # Print all the databases
            with db.cursor() as cur:
                cur.execute('SHOW DATABASES')
                for r in cur:
                    print(r)
        finally:
            db.close()

    print("SSH success !!")
except Exception as e:
    print("Error:", str(e))
```

---

Error: Could not establish session to SSH gateway

I also tried GPT 4, 3.5 and searched a lot of other issues in StackOverFlow, but it doesn't solve it at all. Based on that data, I succeeded when I made a direct ssh connection from the terminal, but I keep getting an error. Someone please help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with your code. I plugged my own values into this and was able to connect to my database through a bastion just fine. Double-check the key path? For what it's worth, it looks like the SSH library will cycle through your .ssh keys and try them all. Maybe it missed the right one?